# Spring security authentication without spring boot doesn't work as opposed to with spring boot and similar configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

### With Spring Boot:

The working Spring Boot + Spring Security application uses this for request mapping:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleLDAPApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleLDAPApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter adapter() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addViewController("/login")
                    .setViewName("login");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

This is the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchBase("ou=Users").userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=bla,ou=Roles").groupSearchFilter("(roleOccupant={0})")
                .contextSource().root("dc=ops,dc=blabla,dc=com").url("ldap://192.168.1.57:389/dc=ops,dc=blabla,dc=com");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

And this is the login page:

```
<div class="content">
    <h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>
    <form name="form" th:action="@{/login}" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Whenever I go to the reserved `/secure` URL, the application correctly redirects me to the login page for authentication.

### Without Spring Boot:

My Spring Security web application without Spring Boot uses the following controller for request mapping:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

The security configuration is completely the same as in the case of Spring Boot application, the only difference being the additional `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation.

The only difference in the view section of my application without Spring Boot is that I use JSP instead of Thymeleaf as in the case of Spring Boot:

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login">
</form>
```

But now when I go to `/secure`, my application incorrectly serves me this page instead of redirecting to the login page. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Spring Boot is simple, Spring itself not so much. My `SecurityConfig` class was not registered with the WAR. So in order to do this, in the same package as `SecurityConfig` I had to create 3 classes.

This:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;

public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
      extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

This:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class RootConfiguration {
}
```

And this:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Why I should do so is explained in details in the [Spring Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/hellomvc-javaconfig.html#security-config-java).